# returning a UIImage where data behind it is released causing bad_access

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I'm using ARC.  I have something like this:

```
-(UIImage *)buildFullResImage
{
   // blah blah does stuff to make a CGImage ref from some data...
   CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(imageWidth, imageHeight, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo, provider, NULL, NO, renderingIntent);
   // then make the uiimage from that
   UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];

   CGImageRelease(imageRef);
   CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
   CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
   free(buffer);

   return myImage;
}
```

Then somewhere else I do this...

```
UIImage *thisImage = [self buildFullResImage];
UIImage *resizedImage = [self imageWithImage:thisImage scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(newWidth, newHeight)];
```

And in the imageWithImage method I'm getting a bad_access crash because the actual image data (in buffer) was released back in buildFullResImage.  I've tried a couple of different imageWithImage methods that can easily be found here on SO. It always crashes on whatever is accessing the passed uiimage's data.  Usually it's crashing on like a:

```
    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, newRect, imageRef);
```

or

```
CGContextDrawImage(thisContext, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height), image);
```

The UIImage when it comes across has an width and height and an address (is not null) but apparently no data behind it... because I released the data before returning the image.  You can't release it after returning it.

I don't want to NOT release the buffer and the imageRef and have a leak.  I don't want to duplicate code or merge the resizing with the building as I won't always need to use the resized version.  I wanted modular code.

I know this seems like objective-c 101 but I've been fighting with it for hours.  I have a dumb quick work around but I'd like to know the right way to do this.

UPDATE..

My dumb work around which is working is that I made buffer, the myImage, and the imageRef all global properties so they stay retained until I'm ready to release them.  I can manage to release them after I'm done using them to save off the image or whatever I'm doing with it.  But it seems like there would be a way to make the UIImage that I'm returning be it's own object with it's own control of it's underlying data.